# In SQL Server 2005+, calculate whether a date falls in a range while excluding certain weekdays

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have an application that passes information to agents in the field via smartphone.  The application is used by multiple clients, and each one can decide how many days forward/backward they want to allow their agents to view, i.e.:

1. Customer1 allows agents to see only today and tomorrow
2. Customer2 allows his agents to see two days back and two days ahead.
3. Customer3 allows his agents to see one week back and one week forward, for a total of 15 days (counting today).

At present, the maximum possible setting is 15 days: -7 days, today, +7 days.

Each customer has his own server with his own DB and his own set of parameters.

Given a range of dates (let's just take all of 2017):

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE 
(
     RowID INT IDENTITY
    ,Stamp DATETIME --Remember, I'm in 2005 and don't have the DATE type
)
;

WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'01/01/2017',101) AS Stamp
        UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,X.Stamp)
    FROM CTE AS X
    WHERE X.Stamp < '12/31/2017'
)
INSERT INTO @TABLE (Stamp)
SELECT Stamp FROM CTE OPTION (MaxRecursion 365)
;
```

And given three parameters - Today's date, a Negative Day Range setting, and a Positive Day Range Setting (either of these, or both, can be 0):

```
DECLARE 
     @GET_DATE DATETIME
    ,@DAY_RANGE_LOW SMALLINT
    ,@DAY_RANGE_HIGH SMALLINT
;
SELECT 
     @GET_DATE = '02/23/2017'   -- Thursday, Feb 23, 2017
    ,@DAY_RANGE_LOW = -1        -- Allow me to see Wednesday, Feb 22, 2017, and today, Thursday, Feb 23, 2017
    ,@DAY_RANGE_HIGH = 1        -- Allow me to see through Friday and Saturday into Sunday, Feb 26, 2017 
                                -- Total days to view = 5 (Wed, Thurs, Fri, Sat, Sun)
;
```

Show me the dates that fall into a range of `@DAY_RANGE_LOW` to `@DAY_RANGE_HIGH` from today, **excluding intermittent Fridays and Saturdays from the range calculation but still showing them as days to be displayed**:

```
SELECT 
     RowID
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Stamp,101) AS Stamp
    ,CASE DATEPART(dw,Stamp)
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Sunday'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Monday'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Tuesday'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Wednesday'
        WHEN 5 THEN 'Thursday'
        WHEN 6 THEN 'Friday'
        WHEN 7 THEN 'Saturday'
    END AS Weekday
FROM @TABLE
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,@GET_DATE,
    DATEADD(DAY,
    CASE
        WHEN @DAY_RANGE_HIGH >= 1 
        AND DATEPART(dw,@GET_DATE) IN (5,6,7)
        AND DATEPART(dw,Stamp) IN (6,7,1)
        AND Stamp >= @GET_DATE
        AND DATEDIFF(DAY,@GET_DATE,Stamp) BETWEEN -7 AND 7
            THEN
            CASE DATEPART(dw,Stamp)
                WHEN 6 THEN -1
                WHEN 7 THEN -2
                WHEN 1 THEN -3
            END
        WHEN @DAY_RANGE_LOW <= -1 
        AND DATEPART(dw,@GET_DATE) = 1
        AND DATEPART(dw,Stamp) IN (5,6,7)
        AND Stamp <= @GET_DATE
        AND DATEDIFF(DAY,@GET_DATE,Stamp) BETWEEN -7 AND 7
            THEN
            CASE DATEPART(dw,Stamp)
                WHEN 5 THEN +3 -- Positive indicator added for clarity only
                WHEN 6 THEN +2
                WHEN 7 THEN +1
            END
        ELSE 0
    END,Stamp)) BETWEEN @DAY_RANGE_LOW AND @DAY_RANGE_HIGH
;
```

This query returns the right results for this example, as well as most other examples I have tried so far:

```
RowID    Stamp        Weekday     |   [Logic]
-----------------------------------------------------
53       02/22/2017   Wednesday   |   [Today -1]
54       02/23/2017   Thursday    |   [Today]
55       02/24/2017   Friday      |   [Intermittent]
56       02/25/2017   Saturday    |   [Intermittent]
57       02/26/2017   Sunday      |   [Today +1]
```

But it's clunky, and inelegant, and I don't love it. Also, if a customer chooses to use the maximum setting, and today is a Saturday, I will see back to last Saturday and forward to next Sunday - but I won't see last Sunday, because of the limitations of the logic. Not ideal, but survivable.

The SQL presented here is just a small example from a pretty massive Stored Procedure which handles the synchronization between multiple tables, but at the moment this is the only part where we've had problems.

Whatever solution I eventually find will have to work in SQL 2005, preferably also in SQL 2000, since some of our customers are using ancient servers.

Any ideas on how this might be better implemented?

Comment: I will not give this as an answer, but since you are going back in time and you then I just want to say that datetimes internal representation is a float where each number is a day, therefore you can do fun tricks like adding 5 days like this: "print cast((cast(getdate() as float) + 5) as datetime)". It isn't really something anyone would recommend though.

Answer (score 1):

This solution will require you adding an additional column to your table, a flag to denote if the date is intermittent or not. The following code should get what you want. I'm testing in SQL Server 2016 but I don't think I used anything that wouldn't work in 2005 or even 2000; it should all be ANSI standard.Additionally, it's a proper SARG so if you have indexes built on your dates it should utilize those for seeks instead of doing a full table scan like your current version.

```
ALTER TABLE [Table]
    ADD IsIntermittent BIT
;
GO

UPDATE [Table]
    SET IsIntermittent = CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw,Stamp) IN (5,6) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
;

DECLARE @testdate DATETIME = '20160225'
    ,@variation TINYINT = 2
;

SELECT *
FROM [Table]
WHERE Stamp BETWEEN
(
    SELECT MIN(Stamp)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            Stamp
        FROM [Table]
        WHERE Stamp < @testdate
            AND IsIntermittent = 1
        ORDER BY Stamp DESC
        OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST (@variation) ROWS ONLY
    ) AS T 
)
AND
(
    SELECT MAX(Stamp)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            Stamp
        FROM [Table]
        WHERE Stamp > @testdate
            AND IsIntermittent = 1
        ORDER BY Stamp
        OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST (@variation) ROWS ONLY
    ) AS T 
)
;
```

This outputs

```
RowID       Stamp                   IsIntermittent
----------- ----------------------- --------------
9550        2016-02-23 00:00:00.000 1
9551        2016-02-24 00:00:00.000 1
9552        2016-02-25 00:00:00.000 0
9553        2016-02-26 00:00:00.000 0
9554        2016-02-27 00:00:00.000 1
9555        2016-02-28 00:00:00.000 1
```

Comment: LOL I love the edit.  You were right the first time...adding a flag wouldn't have been a problem for me. :-) I'll give it a try later and see how it works and get back to you. Thank you so much for the effort put into your answer!